# MySql Find multiple rows for each id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with 3 columns

```
---QID---TEXT---CID---
```

I would like to find 20 rows(QID and TEXT) for each distinct CID. I have already prepared string $cid so that I can use `WHERE IN` statement.

```
SELECT * FROM questions q1
WHERE cid=(SELECT cid 
    FROM questions q2 
    WHERE q2.cid IN ($cids)
    GROUP BY q2.cid)
ORDER BY q1.qid LIMIT 20
```

Thank you!

Comment: What else do you have apart from the "already prepared string $cid"?

Comment: Whay i have done is "SELECT * FROM questions q1  WHERE cid=(SELECT cid FROM questions q2 WHERE q2.cid IN ($cids) Group BY q2.cid) ORDER BY q1.qid LIMIT 3", but this is not going to work.

Comment: I get the following error: "#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense, to me: you're selecting the `cid`'s you already have, based on the `WHERE` clause...

Comment: The query works now. However, it always returns only 20 rows. I need to get 20 rows for each CID. So if i have 3 CIDs, i expect to get 60 rows.

Comment: try using having at the end. i think you can't use where clause with group by. if you want to filter the result, then try having keyword and use it after group by cluase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple query:

```
$query = 'SELECT QID, TEXT FROM yourDb.yourTable WHERE CID = '.$cid;
```

or, if `$cid` is an array:

```
$query = 'SELECT QID, TEXT FROM yourDb.yourTable WHERE CID IN('.implode(',',$cid).')';
```

To get to the results:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=yourDBServer','login','password');
if (!$stmt = $pdo->query($query))
{
    die('query failed');
}
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

For more info on what you can do with the PDO object, refer to [the manual](http://www.php.net/pdo)

A quick fix (but not a good one) might be:

```
$q = 'SELECT QID, TEXT FROM yourDB.yourTB WHERE CID = '.$cid.' LIMIT 20';
```

In the case of `CID IN(1,2,3)`, I'm not sure if there's a strait forward way of doing this. All I can think of is using unions. Mayby [this page](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) can help you out with that.

A fugly fix might also be to `ORDER BY CID ASC`, and insted of using `fetchAll()`, do this:

```
$query = 'SELECT CID,QID, TEXT FROM yourDb.yourTable WHERE CID IN('.implode(',',$cid).')';

//execute query, same as above: $stmt holds results
$results = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    if (!is_array($results[$row['CID']))
    {
        $results[$row['CID']] = array();
    }
    if (count($results[$row['CID']]) < 20)
    {
        $results[$row['CID']][] = $row;
    }
}
```

This way, the `$results` array, will have a key for each `CID` that was found, and that key's value will be an array of up to 20 records...

Comment: How does the query limit to 20 rows per distinct CID?

Comment: good point, forgot about that part of the question. I'll address the issue

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that can be accomplished by using a single query. He would need to loop through the selected `cID` and extract 20 rows for each of them. He would have to store all those rows until he loops through all `cID`, so probably he needs a Stored Procedure with a temporary table to store data. Otherwise, he could try to make a query from PHP for each `cID`, but would have a negative impact on performance.

Comment: I need to get 20 rows for each CID. So if $cid="1,2,3", i expect to get 60 rows. However, if i add LIMIT 20 to this query i will get only 20 rows. Thanks anyway!

Comment: mazzucci, That is exactly what i did not want to do :)

Comment: Yeah, i will try unions. BTW, the link is really great. I am definetely going to read that page. Anyway, I will write a comment here if i get it to work! Thank you!

Comment: Always glad to help... I don't like to nag, but if this answer was helpful, please vote for it

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in using the `=` operator and passing a *set* of values instead of *single* one. Change your query to the following and try again

```
SELECT * FROM questions q1 
WHERE cid 
IN $cids 
ORDER BY q1.qid LIMIT 20
```

Comment: The query works. However, it always returns only 20 rows. I need to get 20 rows for each CID. So if i have 3 CIDs, i expect to get 60 rows.Thanks.

Comment: I use LIMIT 20. Sorry, my mistake:)

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet uses the MySQL variable trick to assign a number for each row per CID.  To keep the example simple I've limited the amount of returned rows to 2 per CID.

```
select  cid
,       qid
,       text
from    (
        select  if(@last_cid = cid, @rn := @rn + 1, @rn := 1) as rn
        ,       (@last_cid := cid)
        ,       cid
        ,       qid
        ,       text
        from    YourTable yt
        cross join
                (select @rn := 0, @last_cid := -1) r
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   rn < 3;
```

Data setup:

```
create table YourTable (QID int, TEXT varchar(50), CID int);
insert YourTable values
    (1, 'hi', 1),
    (1, 'hi', 1),
    (2, 'hi', 1),
    (2, 'hi', 1),
    (3, 'hi', 2),
    (4, 'hi', 2),
    (4, 'hi', 2),
    (5, 'hi', 3);
```

This returns up to two rows per CID:

```
+------+------+------+
| cid  | qid  | text |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 | hi   |
|    1 |    1 | hi   |
|    2 |    3 | hi   |
|    2 |    4 | hi   |
|    3 |    5 | hi   |
+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Wow:) That looks very difficult. I need some time to understand and try it out. I will add a comment later. Thank you!